# How is the negative index in this C code producing the given output?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indices

Here is a C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(char**);

int main() {
  char*argv[] = {"ab","cd","ef","gh"};
  fun(argv);
  return 0;
}

void fun(char**p) {
  char* t;
  t = (p+=sizeof(int))[-1];  //negative index
  printf("%s\n",t);
}
```

I executed this code and got the output as 'gh'. My understanding is that when 
`int* t = &a` where a is an array then t[-2] will make t to point to *(t-2) and that should be some position prior to the current value of t. But here the output is the next value to the current position of t. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

`p+=sizeof(int)` should make p point to `argv[2]`. Then how did 'gh' came as output.

**EDIT** Given that the size of int 2 bytes. It a question from a mock test series. They gave the answer as 'gh'. I too ran the code in my system and got the same answer.

Comment: On most systems these days, the size of an `int` is `4`. Now draw out the array on paper, and draw an arrow to the index `4` in that array. That arrow is the pointer created by `p += sizeof(int)`. Now get the index before that (which is index `-1`).

Comment: `p+=sizeof(int)`, WTF

Comment: Perhaps you should check what `sizeof(int)` actually is on your system.  Although 2 is *possible*, it is unlikely.

Comment: `Given that the size of int 2 bytes`..well, then it's true. However, in most modern system `sizeof(int)` evaluates to `4`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: my bet is OP is using Turbo-C.

Comment: @SouravGhosh 100 of millions of embedded processors in 2016 were 16 bit ones with 2 byte `int`.  C is very popular there.  Even is 4 byte is more common, 2 byte `int` is far more common than _rare_ these days.

Comment: "`p+=sizeof(int)` should make `p` point to `argv[2]`. Then how did `"gh"` came as output?" --> `p+=sizeof(int)` does make `p` point to `argv[2]`, "Given that the size of int 2 bytes."  But that is not the code nor the size of `int` in your case where size of `int` is 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your system `sizeof(int)` turns out to be `4`. Now you added `4` to `p` - at this point after addition it points to one past the end of the array. Now you use `-1` which makes it point to the last position of the array. And you print it and you get `gh`.

```
 "ab" "cd" "ef" "gh"
+----+----+----+----+---
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+---
  ^              ^     ^        
  |              |     |
  p             p+3    p+4
```

And indexing by `-1` means `p+4-1` or `p+3`.

Here also you should check the value of `sizeof(int)` before you do this. in case `sizeof(int)` turns out to be different then the result would vary, maybe even lead to undefined behavior. (In case if on some system `sizeof(int)=8`).

Whatever you said in the end of your question will be valid if `sizeof(int)=2` but again `p+=sizeof(int)` is not very common way to go about.

---

In case `sizeof(int)=2` then it will give `"cd"` as the answer. In case the answer given is something other than `"cd"`, then *it is wrong*.